# Apache reverse proxy: change http-header (requested url)

Tags: apache

I am using Apache 2.2.15 as reverse proxy and I would like to modify the requested address in the HTTP header.

Clients request:

`https://nameA.domain.com` (external DNS)

The reverse Proxy should change the request in the HTTP header to the internal host:

`http://nameB.OTHERdomain.com` (internal host)

I don't know how to manage this.
I added a picture:

[image]

SSL setup and everything else works.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

RequestHeader set Host "nameB.OTHERdomain.com"